# Can't see AutomationID on toolstripbuttons (winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms, automation, toolstripbutton

I'm trying to set the automationid property on a couple of toolstripbuttons in a winforms window so that I can uniquely identify them later with UISpy. However, I am at a loss.

I've set the name & text properties for the buttons but UISpy does not pick up on those. The automationid field is blank! ( "" )

The project has the automation dll referrenced and I am using it (using System.Windows.Automation;). The only additional property I can see after this inclusion is a get-method for the automationid. I would really love a setter!

Anyone knows how to tackle this?
Please let me know if I forgot any information.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the automationid is overrated and the objectname works fine.